# Illegal string offset when using string to reference array

Tags: php, variables

I have classes, each with a date related member variable that always has the same naming format - `field_{$node->type}_date`

For example, if I my node type was 'car', the date field would be named `field_car_date`

So I am looping over all my nodes and I want to access the date related field for each of them. However I am getting an error. Here's the code

```
$date_field_key = 'field_' . $node->type . '_date';
if (isset($node->$date_field_key['und'][0]['value'])) {
```

I get an error because of the second line. The error is - `Illegal string offset 'und'`
The date related variable is an array and it does have an element with the key 'und'. If I write out the line explicitly - `$node->field_car_date['und'][0]['value']` - it works fine. It's just when I dynamically create the field name that I get this problem.

Any solution for this, is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: The syntax is not incorrect, but you express something else with it as you obviously intend to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to surround you key value in `{}` because it's a dynamically-assigned variable.

In your second line, you have `$node->$date_field_key['und'][0]['value']` where you should have:

```
$node->{$date_field_key}['und'][0]['value']
```

Notice the `{}` surrounding the `date_field_key`

Good luck!

Comment: Try: `$node->{$date_field_key}['und'][0]['value']` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not called objet declaration. A little bit more precision with an answer won't be bad, because it is an answer and others expect a certain level of guidance with it.

Comment: You seem to be following me around today, hakra :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to spare the variable:

```
$array = $this->$date_field_key;
$value = $array['und'][0]['value'];
```

If you get it to work, we then can discuss more advanced topics.